# Changing the 'from' email address for gmail action button

Tags: google-schemas

I am using Gmail actions for over a year and now have a need to update the sender email address. How do i make this change? Do i have to redo registration using https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google or is there a simpler process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your new email address is the same domain as the original email you've been whitelisted for, you should fill out the [form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1PA-vjjk3yJF7MLPOVKbIz3MBfhyma2obS8NIZ0JYx8I/viewform?pli=1) and state that you're whitelisted for xxx@mydomain.com and you'd like to be whitelisted for yyy@mydomain.com as well.

If your new email address is a different domain from the original email address you were whitelisted, I'm  sure they'll have to do a quality check on your new email/domain to make sure everything is within their [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google#email_sender_quality_guidelines). In this case, fill out the [form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1PA-vjjk3yJF7MLPOVKbIz3MBfhyma2obS8NIZ0JYx8I/viewform?pli=1), inputting your new email and providing all the details. Basically, redoing the whole registration again.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Franco. I have submitted the form. How long do approvals take?

Comment: I'm not sure, but do let us know ;). If you feel my response was the answer to your question, please mark it as the answer.